# How to extract lat and long values from a google maps link

Tags: android, google-maps, android-webview

I have a web view that shows google maps on my android activity. I am currently getting the link that contains the latitude and longitude values of the selected location by clicking a button. What I want to know is, how can I extract and save the latitude and longitude values in to variables? I tried this code but it doesn't seem to work

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(str);
uri.getQueryParameter(q1);
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the url as a String, named str:

```
String[] part1 = str.split(Pattern.quote("@"));
String[] part2 = part1[1].split(Pattern.quote(","));

double lat = Double.parseDouble(part2[0]);
double lon = Double.parseDouble(part2[1]);
```